# Why resttemplate is not throwing UnknownHttpStatusCodeException but java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

Why resttemplate is not throwing UnknownHttpStatusCodeException but "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0] while using RestTemplate" when an unknown http status code is received?

eg: when RestTemplate.exchange() method returns  an unknown (or custom) HTTP status code, it is supposed to throw UnknownHttpStatusCodeException but actually I found that it returns java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0].

Comment: I wanted to help you out on a Friday night but I dont have anything to work with here. Please be more descriptive of your issue and try posting code samples. Welcome to the community.

Comment: Just added more description. @ShantanuWagh please have a look.

Comment: Here should be a good pointer to know how spring handles it: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException. If the status resolves to null, then it throws `UnknownHttpStatusCodeException`, I think it is throwing `IllegalArgumentException` while resolving

Comment: So do you think it is a bug? Where it could be resolving this? I am not resolving in my code , Just running a test case with some unknown status code and in the exception block it is coming IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Cant help much without seeing the code.